# Como criar propriedade para um Array? VB.NET

Tags: array, vb.net

Tenho uma dúvida em Arrays, não sei se escrevi certo se o que estou me referindo é realmente uma propriedade, vou explicar detalhadamente o que quero fazer.

Por exemplo:

Quero criar um array com vários nomes =

```
dim nomes() as string
```

Após isso queria fazer uma propriedade como por exemplo

```
nomes(0).middleName
nomes(0).FullName
```

Isso é possível? Como crio estas propriedades?

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível. O máximo que você pode fazer é criar uma classe pra isso.

Algo como

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class Program
    Public Shared Sub Main()

        dim names As New List(Of Names)


        names.Add(New Names("Joaquim"))
        names.Add(New Names("Pedro", "Moraes"))

        names(0).LastName = "Barbosa"

        Console.WriteLine(names(0).FullName)
        Console.WriteLine(names(1).FullName)
    End Sub
End Class

Class Names

    Sub New(ByVal first As String)
        Me.m_FirstName = first
    End Sub

    Sub New(ByVal first As String, ByVal last As String)
        Me.m_FirstName = first
        Me.m_LastName = last
    End Sub


    Public Property FirstName() As String
        Get
            Return m_FirstName
        End Get
        Set
            m_FirstName = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName() As String
        Get
            Return m_LastName
        End Get
        Set
            m_LastName = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_LastName As String
    Public ReadOnly Property FullName() As String
        Get
            Return Convert.ToString(FirstName & Convert.ToString(" ")) & LastName
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/acuobA)

Como eu não programo VB.NET, pode ser que haja alguma forma melhor de organizar este código de exemplo. De qualquer, a ideia é essa, criar uma classe e modificar as propriedades desta classe.

Segue também um exemplo em C#.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var nomes = new Names[2]; 
        nomes[0] = new Names {  FirstName = "Pedro" };
        nomes[1] = new Names {  FirstName = "Joaquim", LastName = "Soares" } ;          
        nomes[0].LastName = "Barbosa";

        Console.WriteLine(nomes[0].FullName);
        Console.WriteLine(nomes[1].FullName);
    }
}

class Names
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get {return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BSxTya)